# Generating an alert in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

I am trying to use Selenium IDE to test some funcionality that involves drawing to a canvas.

Since I am not able to check what the web page has really drawn on the canvas, I would like to show an alert , something like "Check that there is a blue rectangle", so that the person doing the test can validate (manually) if the test is successful.

I just can't find anything in the documentation about **generating** an alert in the test case.

I can use an *echo* command , and wait for some time, but I would like to find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an echo with Target = `javascript{alert('Check that there is a blue rectangle')}`

http://snag.gy/jw8WQ.jpg